# Websphere scheduler vs Liberty scheduler

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty

I am working on a project where we  are planning to use WLP (WebSphere liberty) instead of traditional WAS.

The  code is using WAS scheduler for scheduling activities.

Does liberty also have the same level of support/features for scheduler as present in WAS .

How can I migrate the scheduler tasks from websphere to liberty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code using the Scheduler in traditional WebSphere Application Server should not be migrated to EE Concurrency Utilities unless you are certain that you do not need the transactional/persistent quality of service that the Scheduler provides (Scheduler tasks run in a transaction and can roll back and be retried, and they can also persist across server restart). To obtain a similar quality of service in Liberty, you should migrate your Scheduler tasks to Persistent EJB Timers.  Note that while fail over support across multiple servers is not present in Persistent EJB Timers in Liberty at the time of writing this, it is currently being worked on.